# apt-get suggests removing unrelated apps after uninstalling LibreOffice

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get

I'm using Debian 8. I wanted to remove LibreOffice so I executed a command:

```
# sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
```

From the packages that were about to be removed I noticed "gnome" but I confirmed. Now I wanted to clean up so I executed `apt-get autoremove`. apt-get suggested removing some packages I use like gedit, java-common, openjdk, rhythmbox and a plenty of gnome-related packages. Why does it want to remove them? Are there other packages that shouldn't be removed or am I missing something?

> alacarte argyll argyll-ref bijiben ca-certificates-java cheese
>     coinor-libcbc3 coinor-libcgl1 coinor-libclp1 coinor-libcoinmp1
>     coinor-libcoinutils3 coinor-libosi1 default-jre default-jre-headless
>     dleyna-renderer file-roller finger firebird2.5-common firebird2.5-common-doc
>     firebird2.5-server-common fonts-opensymbol fonts-sil-gentium
>     fonts-sil-gentium-basic gedit gedit-common gedit-plugins
>     gir1.2-champlain-0.12 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0
>     gir1.2-git2-glib-1.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-grilo-0.2
>     gir1.2-gtkchamplain-0.12 gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 gir1.2-mediaart-1.0
>     gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-rest-0.7 gir1.2-secret-1 gir1.2-tracker-1.0
>     gir1.2-vte-2.91 gir1.2-zeitgeist-2.0 gir1.2-zpj-0.0 gnome-clocks
>     gnome-color-manager gnome-documents gnome-getting-started-docs gnome-logs
>     gnome-maps gnome-media gnome-music gnome-nettool gnome-photos
>     gnome-shell-extension-weather gnome-sound-recorder gnome-video-effects
>     gnustep-base-common gnustep-base-runtime gnustep-common goobox
>     gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio hamster-applet iputils-tracepath java-common
>     libabw-0.1-1 libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libcdr-0.1-1
>     libclucene-contribs1 libclucene-core1 libcmis-0.4-4 libcoverart0 libdiscid0
>     libe-book-0.1-1 libeot0 libetonyek-0.1-1 libexiv2-13 libexttextcat-2.0-0
>     libexttextcat-data libfbclient2 libfbembed2.5 libfreehand-0.1-1 libgit2-21
>     libgit2-glib-1.0-0 libgltf-0.0-0 libgnustep-base1.24 libgpod-common libgpod4
>     libhyphen0 libidl0 liblangtag-common liblangtag1 liblinear1 libminiupnpc10
>     libmspub-0.1-1 libmwaw-0.3-3 libmythes-1.2-0 libnatpmp1 libobjc4
>     libodfgen-0.1-1 liborbit2 liborcus-0.8-0 librhythmbox-core8 libsgutils2-2
>     libsofia-sip-ua-glib3 libsofia-sip-ua0 libvisio-0.1-1 libwnck-common
>     libwnck22 libwps-0.3-3 lp-solve media-player-info minissdpd nautilus-sendto
>     ndiff nmap openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless p7zip-full polari
>     python-gconf python-gnome2 python-pyorbit python-wnck python3-gi-cairo
>     python3-mako python3-markupsafe rhythmbox rhythmbox-data
>     rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugins seahorse simple-scan
>     telepathy-rakia transmission-common transmission-gtk tzdata-java unar
>     uno-libs3 ure xdg-user-dirs-gtk

Comment: If you're using e.g. java, you have to install it manually, so the system knows you're using it. Right now, java got installed on your computer just because libre office needed it.

Answer (score 1):

The command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
```

...removed the GNOME Desktop Environment including some extra components. To reinstall them run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

The [gnome](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/gnome) meta-package depends on the standard distribution of the GNOME desktop environment, plus a complete range of plugins and other applications integrating with GNOME and Debian, providing the best possible environment to date.

To get a preview of some of the other packages that the gnome package will install run this command:

```
apt-cache show gnome
```